# Pairing bluetooth headset fails with error org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationTimeout

Tags: arch-linux, audio, manjaro, bluetooth

I'm having a problem connecting to my Bluetooth headset. I *can* pair it to other systems, so I know it's working, however, on my new laptop on which I recently installed Manjaro i3, it fails.

This is what I'm doing (and the output I see):

```
bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# agent on
[bluetooth]# default-agent
[bluetooth]# scan on    <-- finds my headset
[bluetooth]# trust <mac>
Changing <mac> trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# pair <mac>
Attempting to pair with <mac>
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationTimeout
[bluetooth]#
```

I've been going through the internet for the past 4 hours, but I didn't find any solution.

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so I'll write an answer. Here is a checklist of things you can try:

- (basic) make sure the headphones are in the 'discoverable/ scanning' state. On mine, I have to hold the button down for 5 seconds.
- While on `bluetoothctl`, run `show`, which will display the controller's (current Bluetooth device)  info. See if *powered* is really *on*

#### Debug

- You can run `sudo tail -f /var/log/kern.log` to log more information about your system. Maybe you find something useful
- Also, the command `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` will return some
- Try running `rfkill list`, you will get something similar to:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Check if maybe your Bluetooth is not blocked. If `Hard blocked: yes`, then there might be some buttons combo on your machine to enable the bluetooth ex: *Fn+F3*. You can just unblock both by running `rfkill unblock bluetooth`. And maybe check now if it works.

I'm still researching and will edit my answer if I find new info. Currently having issues with my Bluetooth driver.
If you already have found a solution, I would love to learn about it.

Comment: Thank you @DariusP for the answer. I gave up on that headset because I couldn't make it work. The only conclusion that I could think of was that, for some reason, the Bluetooth isn't compatible with my new laptop. I tried sooo many headsets after that and ended up sticking with one, but I'm still missing that one... it was very good